# Analyzing Clickstream data through firebase

Tags: android, ios, google-bigquery, clickstream

Let me pitch my situation and see what you think the best solution is.

Problem: Trying to analyze clickstream data.

Current Situation: Currently we have data flowing into google firebase to analyze app activity. it works great to measure MUA and some basic event analysis.  However, i'd love to drill deeper and be able to query the data myself. For example we have an event setup to show when a user views the rate structure of a parking garage. I have an event that tells me how often a user starts a session then clicks that...but nothing that tells me how often they do that at each location.

I have begun to use bigquery to attempt to analyze this but its a little clunky.  Partly because I'm still getting used to it.  Are there any other ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: BigQuery is the best way to analyze that data. However, it takes some time to adapting to it. After you get used to it, you can analyze your data with all details, so I'd recommend you to continue this way.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sabri mentioned, BigQuery can help you achieve a detailed analysis using SQL.
To export your Firebase data, you can use the feature: 'BigQuery Export for Firebase' to export Google Analytics for Firebase information to BigQuery.
Additionally, I recommend that you contact [the Firebase support team](https://firebase.google.com/support), they can tell you if the exporting feature, exports all the information you need for your requirements.